# Would it be more efficient to define a parser through a pointer in a list, or to pass the list recursively?

Tags: parsing, haskell, recursion, lazy-evaluation

In C/C++ we use pointers and stuff like that to save memory when parsing through a large array of characters. Would the same be used for Haskell? I've seen some parser implementations that accept/return the "remaining characters to be parsed" in Haskell - does the compiler take care of the massive amount of memory being passed around? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There isn't such a massive amount of memory passed around. What's actually passed when "the remaining characters to be parsed" are passed is a pointer into the list, not a copy of the part of the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the same idea would be used in Haskell; however, it's pretty easy with GHC, because all (boxed) values are pointers to begin with. So you don't need to do anything special to take advantage of this common trick... just write your code.

Comment: Boxed values? Is there any documentation for designing haskell code to be compliant with this so ghc can take advantage of it?

Comment: @AthanClark By default, all the stuff you deal with is boxed. You have to work hard (and enable language extensions and import low-level modules with GHC in their name) to have a value that isn't boxed.

Comment: @AthanClark ...that is to say, no, there's no documentation about how to make boxed values, because that's the easy thing to do. All the documentation is about how to step outside of the norm and enable the crazy stuff.

Comment: ahh okay. Awesome, I look forward to understanding more about haskell's implementation techniques and advantageous design. Thank you!!